# 'del /s *.svn' returns "Access is denied" error on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, svn

I'm trying to delete all `.svn` files from a folder and all of its subfolders so I'm doing this from the command line:

```
del /s *.svn
```

However, all I get is this for each `.svn` file:

> Access is denied.

How do I make sure I can delete all of the `.svn` files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what may be happening is that your del command isn't properly matching the ".svn" folder. I had the same problem and solved it using PowerShell like the following:

`powershell.exe "Get-ChildItem .\foldername -include .svn -Recurse -Force | Remove-Item -Recurse -Force"`

Using the above without the pipe to Remove-Item will show you the results without also deleting them.

Comment: Still had to run this in a Command Window with Administrative privileges so not sure if it is any better.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be a Administrator to do the following
Open up a command prompt window in the the directory that this folder (Quick way: `shift+right click` the current directory and click `Open Command Prompt Here`) then type `takeown /f directory_name /r /d y` where directory_name is the name of the directory with the *.svn files and then type `icacls directory_name /grant administrators:F /t`.

Now try deleting the files again, however you can also try `del /f /s *.svn`.